# How to format this data to send to a serial port?

Tags: c++, serial-port, boost-asio

I am trying to send commands and receive data from a hardware device via a serial port in Windows.

The documentation has the following information:

[image]

There is also an example command given in the documentation, which looks like this:

```
Client: $02 $30 $34 $30 $31 $30 $33 $32 $41 $03
```

which should result in the returned data:

```
$02 $30 $34 $30 $35 $30 $33 $30 $32 $33 $30 $32 $37 $41 $36 $44 $33 $03
```

When I send the command in full `$02 $30 $34 $30 $31 $30 $33 $32 $41 $03` as Hex, in a serial port monitor application, I indeed get the data return. In my c++ application however, I get nothing.

I am using boost::asio in c++, and have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        asio::io_service io;
        asio::serial_port port(io);

        port.open("COM4");
        port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200)); 
        
        uint8_t obuf[512]; // arbitrary size, larger than largest expected buffer
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 512; ++i) obuf[i] = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            port.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(char(0x02) + "0401032A" + char(0x03), 10));

            //$02 $30 $34 $30 $31 $30 $33 $32 $41 $03
            std::cout << "reading" << std::endl;
            asio::read(port, asio::buffer(obuf,10));
    
            std::cout << obuf << std::endl; 
    
        }
    

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Where am I going wrong in the formatting here? How can I send this command '$02 $30 $34 $30 $31 $30 $33 $32 $41 $03' as ASCI to a port in c++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug:

```
 char(0x02) + "0401032A" + char(0x03)
```

It adds integral types (char, char const* and char). What you likely wanted is

```
 char(0x02) + std::string("0401032A") + char(0x03), 10)

 // or

 char(0x02) + "0401032A"s + char(0x03)

 // or indeed, much simpler:
 "\x02" "0401032A0\x03"s
```

> Keep in mind that if you want to construct a std::string from a literal constant using the constructor, you may have to specify a length when the data includes embedded NUL characters.
>
> This is not required for `""s"` and `""sv` literals, so usually you should prefer them

### Side Note

Use  `asio::write` instead of `write_some` so you get more guarantees that the whole buffer is transmitted (except of course in the face of errors).

Also use the return value to resize your actual message received.

### Improvement suggestions:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    asio::io_service  io;
    asio::serial_port port(io);

    port.open("COM4");
    port.set_option(asio::serial_port_base::baud_rate(115200));

    while (true) {
        boost::asio::write(port, boost::asio::buffer("\x02"
                                               "0401032A0\x03"sv));

        //$02 $30 $34 $30 $31 $30 $33 $32 $41 $03
        std::cout << "reading" << std::endl;
        std::vector<uint8_t> obuf(10, 0);
        auto n = asio::read(port, asio::buffer(obuf));
        obuf.resize(n);

        for (int i : obuf) {
            std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << " " << i;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried `port.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(char(0x02) + std::string("0401032A") + char(0x03), 10));` and I still get no result.  Changing to `port.write` gives me `boost::asio::serial_port has no member 'write'`. Do I need to adjust my code elsewhere to make this change?

Comment: I just added a listing with the imrovements I'd suggest. Indeed [`asio::write` is a free function](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/write.html).

Comment: Thank you! I am seeing errors on the write line, what is `sv` ? And does it need a comma before it?

Comment: I choise the `std::string_view` literal operator `""sv` just for demo. You can use `""s` if your compiler doesn't have `std::string_view` yet. "It" likely doesn't need a comma before "it" (? where) because it compiles as written: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/71c83d49d7d0df87

Comment: (for reference [string literals in c++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) can be split, which is required here because otherwise the hex character escape would be ambiguous: [_"Hexadecimal escape sequences have no length limit and terminate at the first character that is not a valid hexadecimal digit"_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape#:~:text=hexadecimal%20escape%20sequences%20have%20no%20length%20limit%20and%20terminate%20at%20the%20first%20character%20that%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20hexadecimal%20digit))

Comment: Okay got it. Changing the `sv` to `s` has it compiling. However the code still blocks on `read` and does not return any data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234262/discussion-between-sehe-and-anti).

Comment: As discussed in chat, this solves the issue:  `boost::asio::write(
   port, boost::asio::buffer("\x02\x30\x34\x30\x31\x30\x33\x32\x41\x03"s));`

Thank you very much!